# About the number of disjoint cycles in a product of permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am being troubled by a quick doubt on products of permutations. Concretely suppose we have the permutation

$$(123\dots n)^k,\quad\text{for some}\quad k=1,\dots,n$$

I wish to find the **number** of disjoint cycles that this product decomposes to. I recall a couple of facts regarding order of permutations such as:

**Proposition 1:** For an element $g\in G$, a group, with order $n$, the order of $g^k$ is $n/\text{gcd}(n,k)$.

Also, for disjoint cycles it holds that:

**Proposition 2:** If $\pi\in S_n$ can be decomposed into $\pi=\sigma_1\dots\sigma_r$, then the order of $\pi$ is $\text{lcm}(\text{length}(\sigma_1),\dots,\text{length}(\sigma_r))$.

Combining these facts for my permutation we get

$$\text{lcm}(\text{length}(\sigma_1),\dots,\text{length}(\sigma_r))=n/\text{gcd}(n,k)$$

I can also switch the right hand side to $\text{lcm}(n,k)/k$, but this still doesn't help me a lot.

How can I find such $r$?

And more in general, if I had a product of permutations, how do I find the number of disjoint cycles it decomposes into? Any help will be kindly appreciated.

**EDIT:** The [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574501/raising-a-cycle-to-a-power-cycle-decomposition) does answer the doubt about the cycle decomposition of powers of a cycle. But I still have troubles in the more general case. If for example, I were to multiply the cycle in question by a transposition, how would I get the cycle decomposition of that permutation?

Comment: Note that just finding the order isn't sufficient, since $(34)$ and $(12)(34)$ both have order 2 but have a distinct number of disjoint cycles. Thus, you'd need a bit more understanding/description to count the cycles.

Comment: You're correct! My intuition was a bit shaky, I just recalled the facts but they didn't line up. Luckily my question had already been answered. I just didn't look quite hard enough here.